# call web service method with arguments in javascript using callback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, callback

I have a web service method:

```
namespace myNamSpace
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, 
    // using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class myClass : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public DataSet login(string strClientCertificate, string strClientChallengeSigned, string MsgChallenge, string rndNum)
        {
           //some codes
           return ds; // return data set
        }
     }
```

I want to call this method in my javascript using callback function so I have:

```
myNameSpace.myClass.login(cert, sign, msg, rndNum, succeededCallBack,failedCallBack);
function succeededCallBack(xmlDocument)
{
   alert("HERE!");
}
function failedCallBack(error)
{
   alert(error);
}
```

when I debug the code, after calling my login `webMethod`, nothing is happened. I mean I have not got any `"HERE!"` or error alert from my script. Does anyone know anything about it? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please check if any error in browser console

Comment: There is no error in browser console and everything is fine!

Comment: which browser did u check??

Comment: IE with script debugging mode

Comment: You can't return a dataset I think. return something else alternatively

Comment: it's advisable to check the intellitrace events of visualstudio in such scenarios. It will show  the reason for the response in its console (as exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a  class to create the objects as required.

```
       [WebMethod]
    public List<MyRow> login(string strClientCertificate, string strClientChallengeSigned, string MsgChallenge, string rndNum)
          {
       List<MyRow> MyTable = new List<MyRow>();

            foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
             {
              MyRow obj = new MyRow();
              obj.column1=dr["column1"].ToString();
              obj.column2=dr["column2"].ToString();
              MyTable.Add(obj );

          }
       return MyTable;
       }

        public class MyRow
          {
           public string column1{get;set;}
           public string column2{get;set;}
          }
```

A circular exception will be thrown if attempted to return a DataTable.

The circular reference is likely due to DataTable having a Columns property, and each DataColumn object has a Table property. When properties are mutually refernced, then it will be difficult to serialize into `[json][1]`.

json is the notation used for data interchange between asp.net and javascript. Read more about jSon and you will come to know more about it. Read well, Google well.

Comment: Ok, that's working fine. By the way, I have no clue why javascript can not handle dataSet type, do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a asp:script manager in your page body form

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scpt" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
```

Try with a simple wen method like below:

```
[WebMethod]
    public stringHello(string strClientCertificate, string strClientChallengeSigned, string MsgChallenge, string rndNum)
    {
       return "hello"; // return data set
    }
```

Comment: try putting a break point in the web service code...and see if it's getting hit

Comment: Ok, now there is something wrong. The break point inside the web service method 'login' is not getting hit.

Comment: Do you have any idea why? I've already call another method (with no arguments) with this method and it returns proper value

Comment: I added a simple method to my service which get one argument and it is  working fine!! I am totally confused! what is happening here?

Comment: try changing ur dataset type to string